# Associated Laguerre polynomials of half-integer parameters

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

It appears that [associated Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials) $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x^2)$ for half integer parameters in $n$ and $\alpha$ may be expressed in terms of an exponential function, an imaginary error function and polynomials of degree $2n$. For instance, with $\alpha=-1/2$ and various values of $n$:

- $L_{1/2}^{(-1/2)}(x^2) = \frac{2}{\pi}e^{x^2} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(-x)\operatorname{erfi}(x)$
- $L_{3/2}^{(-1/2)}(x^2) = \frac{4}{3\pi}(1-x^2)e^{x^2} + \frac{2}{3\sqrt{\pi}}(-3x+2x^3)\operatorname{erfi}(x)$
- $L_{5/2}^{(-1/2)}(x^2) = \frac{4}{15\pi}(4-9x^2+2x^4)e^{x^2} + \frac{2}{15\sqrt{\pi}}(-15x+20x^3-4x^5)\operatorname{erfi}(x)$
- $L_{7/2}^{(-1/2)}(x^2) = \frac{4}{105\pi}(24-87x^2+40x^4-4x^6)e^{x^2} + \frac{2}{105\sqrt{\pi}}(-105x+210x^3-84x^5+8x^7)\operatorname{erfi}(x)$

This seems to continue for arbitrary large $n$ with the same pattern. However, at [functions.wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/), the most extensive collection of formulas to my knowledge, I can't find any general relation for that. One can make a connection to confluent hypergeometric functions ${}_1F_1$, parabolic cylinder functions as well as Hermite polynomials, but still I cannot find an explicit expression for the stated formulas at arbitrary half-integer $n$.

Can anyone determine a formula for the polynomials in the above terms for arbitrary half-integer $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some computations with Wolfram Mathematica the general result is that
$$ L_{n+1/2}^{(-1/2)}(-x) = p_n(x)\ \frac{e^{-x}}{ (2n+1)!!\ \pi/2}
 + q_n(x)  \sqrt{x}\text{ erf}(\sqrt{x})\ 
\frac{2^{n+1} n!}{(2n+1)!\sqrt{\pi}} \tag{1} $$
where $\ p_n(x),\ q_n(x)\ $ are polynomials of degree $\ n\ $ with positive integer coefficients.
$$ q_n(x) := 2^n\ n! \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1/2 \choose n-k}\ x^k/k!. \tag{2} $$
$p_n(x)\ $ is defined recursively by
$$ p_0(x) = 1,\;\; p_1(x) = 2+2x, \\
 p_n(x) = (4n-1 + 2x)\ p_{n-1}(x) + (2n-1)\ (2n-2)\ p_{n-2}(x). \tag{3} $$
The coefficients of $\ q_n(x)\ $ are [OEIS sequence A223523](https://oeis.org/A223523).
The coefficients of $\ p_n(x)\ $ are currently **not** in the OEIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a reference for these derivations?

Comment: @user3236841 I don't know of any. I derived them myself I think.

Comment: Thanks! I would suggest publishing this at least on arXiv if you have interest. At least then, peope will be able to directly credit your work. Likely, it will not take long to do so, since you already have the proof. Of course, formal peer review is better, but you may not want to go through the hassle. Is there still no reference for the $p_n$ functions? The derivations are very cool, BTW.

Comment: @user3236841 When I wrote "derived", I meant I found them empirically. I have yet no proofs. I have not yet entered the $p_n(x)$ coefficients into OEIS. You have reminded me that I should do it.

Comment: I see: how did you find them empirically? Btw, would you know where these half-integer parameters that the OP references comes from? I could not find them in Wikipedia. How does the first expression come by?

Comment: @user3236841 I used Matematica and worked out the pattern. For example `Table[LaguerreL[n+1/2, -1/2, -x] //FunctionExpand//Simplify, {n, 0, 4}] //Column`. The OP states "It appears that" and probably did something similar to what I did.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is a recursive relationship in definitng the $L_{\frac n2}^{(-\frac12)}(x)$.